# Angular Copy not working and same types

Tags: angularjs, arrays, copy

I´m trying to copy an object into another, but the destination keeps remaining as in the declaration. I´ve already checked and the types of the variables are the same, I also tried using `[]` and `{}`.
controller comes from:

```
var controller = this; controller.product = [];
```

Here are my results.

```
controller.addPosition = function(){
    var position = {};
    console.log(controller.product);
    angular.copy(controller.product, position);
    console.log(position);
};
```

This is how I copy the array.

[image]

Here is what the browser shows the log.

Comment: Post code as text, not as an image. And post a complete minimal example, including the definition of controller.product. Given the console log, I'd guess that you're adding attributes to an array. Use an object to store attributes, and an array for a vector of values.

Comment: Done, change the definition of controller.product = [] to {} and worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was using

```
var controller = this;
controller.product = [];
```

As a suggestion of @JB Nizet I just changed the `[]` for `{}` and worked.